# How do i fix the "Attach" thing on the debug menu of Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

If i use anything newer than .net 4.8 it just says "attach" instead of "start". How do i fix that???

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DCZO.png)

I tried installng the SDK again, different SDks. Nothing worked. I tried reinstalling Visual Studio itself, but nothing worked.